# How to get a list of processes currently running in Azure VM in UWP app

Tags: c#, azure, uwp

I was wondering if anyone could help me with a feature I'd like to add to one of my utilities. I have a sort of control panel app made in UWP, and I'd like to incorporate a feature that gives you a view of whether a batch processor is running on an azure vm.

So a layman's idea of what I want is, I want to get what appears in Task Managers processes tab, and display it in my app.

I've gone down a few routes on how to do it, but I seem to be running into stumbling blocks around UWP itself, or the Azure platform, or both.

So I've looked at a fair bit of documentation, the most helpful of which are these:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses?view=netframework-4.8

```
        // Get all instances of Notepad running on the specific computer, using machine name.
        Process[] remoteByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad", "myComputer");
```

This would be ideal for me, but it doesn't appear to work with the UWP platform.

I get: 
InvalidOperationException: Process performance counter is disabled, so the requested operation cannot be performed.

Going down the rabbit hole on that error doesn't seem to provide any solutions for my use case.

And I also looked at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/csharp

```
var vm = azure.VirtualMachines.GetByResourceGroup(groupName, vmName);
```

But this requires me adding applications to our azure portal, something I'd rather not do if I can help it.

I've also tried to go down the route of impersonation, but the vm itself doesn't appear to allow that.

Can any of you provide any best practise methods with the above constraints that might get me this information?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do this by adding a fulltrust desktop extension to your UWP. In that extension you can then make the GetProcessByName() call and pass the information back to your UWP. Some info on how to add a fulltrut extension here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher,  a full tutorial on my blog here: https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT : Could you please add this as an answer. It will help others who have the same ask.

Comment: ok, done. Moved this to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "GetProcessByName" approach in UWP by adding a fulltrust desktop extension to your UWP. In that extension you can then make the GetProcessByName() call and pass the information back to your UWP. Some info on how to add a fulltrut extension here: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/…, a full tutorial on my blog here: stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1

I would agree this is more convoluted that one would hope for, but it's how can work around the UWP appcontainer limitation here.